# Are for-loops conditions able to be changed midloop?

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

In java programming: 
I have something along the lines of

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

int listSize = list.size();

for(int x = 0; x< listSize; x++){
    list.remove(x);
    listSize = list.size();
}
```

will this work well enough? or will the for loop keep running. Thanks!

Comment: No, you can't change the condition itself, but you can call `break;` to stop executing a loop. Alternatively, you can change `listSize` to something else to reduce execution length, but this is bad practice.

Comment: @Kon That is a answer, not a comment. Make it such and get the upvotes/accept

Answer (score 3):

I'm a bit concerned at what you're attempting to do here.  Any time someone wants to remove items from a collection in a loop without using an `Iterator`, alarms usually go off.

So, to answer the question **as stated**:  If you change your loop invariant, then you'll get some funky behavior.  This is why it's often called an "invariant"; you don't *want* to change it.  You're certainly welcome to, but you're playing with fire here.

But, let's assume that we have a list of 5 elements in it and we execute your code as is.

```
List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList("word", "another word", "let's go", "keep it up", "get moving");

int length = stringList.size();

for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    System.out.println(stringList.remove(i));
    length = stringList.size();
}

System.out.println("done");
```

If you're expecting it to print out every word in the list, then think again.  It will skip every element because we are changing the content of the list while iterating over it.  When deleting elements from an ArrayList, the underlying implementation will shift over elements to the left in where it was deleted. So, if you delete from position 0, every element now lives to the left of its original position (so element 1 is now element 0).

A quick run-through:

- First iteration, `i = 0`; `"word"` is removed.  Size is changed to 4, `i` increases to 1.
- Second iteration, `i = 1`; `"let's go"` is removed.  Size is changed to 3, `i` increases to 2.
- Third iteration, `i = 2`; `"get moving"` is removed.  SIze is changed to 2, `i` increases to 3.
- No further iteration happens as the condition is not satisfiable.

If you want to cleanly remove *all* items from the collection *without* printing them out, then `ArrayList#clear()` is what you're looking for.  If you want to remove elements one at a time, then use an `Iterator` instead:

```
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("word", "another word", "let's go", "keep it up", "get moving"));

for(Iterator<String> stringIterator = stringList.iterator(); stringIterator.hasNext(); ) {
    System.out.println(stringIterator.next());
    stringIterator.remove();
}

System.out.println("done");
```

Comment: The real goal of my program is that I have to compare items in the list to each other to group them together to print.  This was just my first idea on how to do it. (and i was curious about the for loop condition part also)

Answer (score 1):

The loop won't keep running and it will end without any exception. But the result may not what you expect.
Besides "ArrayList#clear()" or Iterator way to remove all elements from one array. You can also try below codes, just remove "x++" from your loop condition.

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

int listSize = list.size();

for(int x = 0; x< listSize;){
  list.remove(x);
  listSize = list.size();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it in a "while" loop?

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

int listSize = list.size();

while(list.size() != 0){
    list.remove(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically, the computer science course would likely tell you to do it something like this:

```
public void solve() {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    Iterator iter = list.iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println("Next value is: " + iter.next());
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```